# Android standard Icons for use in commercial apps?

Tags: android

These are the standarad icons I am referring to.
http://speckyboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/android_gui_11.jpg

Are these able to be used in apps that are for sale. I am assuming not. But it would save some time if I could use any.

Comment: yes, you can.Any one can use android standard icons for their application development.

Comment: for application development do you mean pre release or post as well. I mean including them in a pay for app

Comment: Yes, you can, in pay app also, If you are using android default views and components in pay app then why sholuld not use Android standard icons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These icons are available in the sdk (`platforms\android-XX\data\res\drawable-[whatever]`), so I would think they could be used in your commercial app.  When you use these, you can access them via `android.R.drawable`, but it is better practice to copy the files and include them in your project for consistency.

Comment: Great news sounds perfect for my needs. Copying and using them, to guarantee the same look across devices of multiple Android versions

Answer (score 2):

If your purpose is only to save time, you can take a look into [Iconspedia](http://www.iconspedia.com/)
site, it has lots of icons of very good quality and you can search by license type. 
Also, they usually come on different sizes and formats.

Comment: Thanks for the tip may come in handy in the future. I think if I can I shall use the stock images provided with android.

Answer (score 2):

There are many icons on the [official Android Developer resource](http://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html)

Comment: Awesome link - if someone knows more links like this - please feel free to share.